# Problem in saving the user data in nest.js using typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

when i'm trying to build CRUD using nest.js with postgres sql using TypeOrm this error appears to me which prevent me from making a new row in database and crash my nest.js application and told me `"no overload matches this call"`

```
 async createUser(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
    const newUser = this.userRepository.create(createUserDto);
    return await this.userRepository.save(newUser);
  }
```

I'm trying to make it
`.save({...createUserDto})`
and make is as This
`.save([...createUserDto])`
but this tries doesn't work

Comment: could you provde snippet of the error or a screenshot for better understanding